# Ubuntu: Is there a GUI for reading my mail (sent by running processes like crontab)?

Tags: ubuntu, email, claws-mail

I have hundreds of mail sent by crontab. It is extremely tedious to go through them one by one on the command line and read/delete them.

Is there a GUI that allows me to do that (so I can block select/delete them etc? - I am totally not loving the CLI).

I installed claws-mail, but it appeara to be pointing to a different mail queue - any help?

I am running Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I managed to setup evolution to read my emails, using the info here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-forward-roots-mail-to-your-inbox.html

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer, but `mail` *does* allow `d 4-10` or `d *` to mass-delete messages.

Also, `mutt` is very popular (although some find `alpine` easier to use).

Answer (score 0):

in Claws Mail you create a Local account, and (normally) in the Account config the 'Local mailbox' field would contain '/var/mail' (without quotes) (works here for years!)